# Android TabPage Indicator content wrapping issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tabpage, indicator, viewpagerindicator

I've encountered another issue with ViewPager and I can't solve it with my current knowledge right now.

I have TabPageIndicator with ViewPager and on every tab, I'm showing text. It's simple textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator$TabView" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vpi_tab_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textColor="@drawable/vpi_tab_text_color"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</view>
```

I want the text in the tab to be always a single line and to be always whole text, not ellipsize, no wrapping, no more than 1 line. It's required for the user to be able to read it whole...

But I can't do that, I've tried different options and I still encounter some problems - either the text has more than just one line, but only the first one is displayed, or only a part of the text is displayed.

Have you experienced something similar?

Any help is appreciated

EDIT ONE:

I believe that the problem is here:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
final boolean lockedExpanded = widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
setFillViewport(lockedExpanded);
    final int childCount = mTabLayout.getChildCount();
    if (childCount > 1 && (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)) {
        if (childCount > 2) {
            mMaxTabWidth = (int) (MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 0.4f);
        } else {
            mMaxTabWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) / 2;
        }
    } else {
        mMaxTabWidth = -1;
    }

    final int oldWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int newWidth = getMeasuredWidth();

    if (lockedExpanded && oldWidth != newWidth) {
        // Recenter the tab display if we're at a new (scrollable) size.
        setCurrentItem(mSelectedTabIndex);
    }
 }
```

mMaxTabWidth...

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue was simple, I commented out this part:

```
        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            // Re-measure if we went beyond our maximum size.
//          if (mParent.mMaxTabWidth > 0 && getMeasuredWidth() > mParent.mMaxTabWidth) {
//              super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mParent.mMaxTabWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), heightMeasureSpec);
//          }
        }
```

Now it works the way I wanted... I was looking at the wrong parts of the code all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with it ellipsizing text in the tabs when it shouldn't. I found the fix [here, #227](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/227#issuecomment-18881187) using @larham's suggestion. Here's basically what he did, but it would be a good idea to read his explanation of what he did and why he did it:

In TabPageIndicator.java, replace the following:

```
mTabLayout.addView(tabView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, MATCH_PARENT, 1));
```

with:

```
mTabLayout.addView(tabView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT, 1));
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, whole text was not shown.
I solved it reducing left/right style padding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Layout weight=1 for the width, I used the Wrap content attribute.
In the TabPageIndicator class, the addTab(int,CharSequence,int) method, replace the   mTabLayout.addView with the following:

mTabLayout.addView(tabView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

Answer (score 0):

update the ViewPageIndicator Library :) was officially fixed :)

Comment: the question was: "Have you experienced something similar? Any help is appreciated" .. i had the same problem, and it was fixed to pull the newest version from the git repo. so why not?